# how to get my Authenticator app - Team2Swift account?

Tags: authentication, 12factor

[screenshot from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1aac.jpg)I have used the authenticator app from team2Swift, It has been nearly 10 day I have used , now the app is auto updated, now when i open the app it says, get started with your first 2FA.

Is there any way to recover it ? or is that a bug from the app and are they trying to resolve it?